# Restrict access to a new created folder to only my android app

Tags: java, android, directory

In android, I created a new folder (if not existing) for my app whenever the app is installed.

Now I want that the folder is only accessed by my app and no other gallery or file explorer app so that the folder's data is read only by my app.

How can I restrict the access of that folder in above mentioned way?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: If you add an empty file in the directory, called .nomedia, the files in that folder (if they are images, or video) will not appear in gallery, but will be still accesible if the user uses a file explorer.

Answer (score 2):

> Internal Storage
>   Store private data on the device memory.
>
> By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user).

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Well what I tried to say is suppose there is a download option for images in Instagram, so you can access those images only through instagram app and not in gallery. I can't stop that access from gallery right now.